# Question regarding $A = B^{-1}DB$ and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $A = B^{-1}DB$, where $A$ is a normal matrix represented by unitary matrices $B, B^{-1}$ and the diagonal matrix $D$.

Although $B^{-1}B = BB^{-1} = I_B$ why doesn't $B^{-1}DB$ give you $D$? What special algebraic properties are revealed about two matrices being similar? (In other words, what is the significance of this equation other than a change-of-base)?

What does it mean for two matrices to have the same determinant? I can do all these "cool" calculations yet have no access to insight of them. (For example, two similar matrices have the same determinant...

More specifically, this is what I'm after: **Are $A$ and $D$ algebraically related?**

Comment: In general, matrix multiplication isn't commutative: you can't change DB  to BD, which you'd need to do before you could cancel the $B^{-1}B$.

Comment: Have a look at the properties listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity

Comment: @John: More specifically, what does it give you? A multiple of $A$?

Comment: Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/similar-matrices-have-the-same-eigenvalues-with-the-same-geometric-multiplicity).

Comment: This is not a trivial answer!!!

Comment: @Mhenni: Why are you yelling?

Comment: @DonLarynx: I am not addressing this to you. Do not worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property#Commutative_operations_in_mathematics). That means that we *cannot* assume that $MN = NM$ for any pair of matrices where $MN$ and $NM$ make sense, i.e. square matrices. There are some matrices which satisfy the equation $MN=NM$, but *not all*.

One direct consequence is that $B^{-1}DB$ is *not necessarily* the same as $D$. You will be able to find specific matrices for which $B^{-1}DB=D$ but, in general, this is impossible.

If we consider non-singular matrices then we have a group. Given a fixed matrix $D$, there set of matrices $B^{-1}DB$, where $B$ is any other non-singular matrix is called the [conjugacy class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) of $D$.

If you want $B^{-1}DB=D$ for all $D$ then you require the conjugacy class of $D$ to comprise $D$ alone. For that to happen, you need $D$ to lie in the [centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_a_group) of the matrix group.

Comment: Are the nice matrices the normal matrices and the unitary matrices, that is, those that satisfy $MN = NM$? (I'm asking if they are nice)

Comment: $B^{-1}DB = D$ iff it's unitary?

Comment: What do you mean by *unitary*? The Unitary matrices $U(n)$ are $n$-by-$n$ complex matrices which preserve the Hermitian inner product, i.e. $X\overline{X}^{\top} = E$, where $E$ is the $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix.

Comment: isn't it unitary if the product $MN = NM = I$?

Comment: **Are they nice**?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix