# similar matrices-eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that similar matrices have the same eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors, I get the following notation:

$$(P^{-1} A  P)\cdot v=\lambda v\rightarrow(P^{-1} A  P)\cdot P^{-1}v=\lambda P^{-1}v$$

Why do we multiple both sides with $P^{-1}$?

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/similar-matrices-have-the-same-eigenvalues-with-the-same-geometric-multiplicity?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you write is either wrong, or uses $v$ for two different vectors, which is probably what is confusing you. Here's what it should say:

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Then let $v \ne 0$ be some corresponding eigenvector.
We have that
$$
Av = \lambda v
$$
Now consider the nonzero vector $w = P^{-1} v$.
Notice that
$$
(P^{-1} A P) w
= P^{-1} A P P^{-1} v
= P^{-1} A v = P^{-1} (\lambda v)
= \lambda (P^{-1} v) = \lambda w.
$$
Therefore, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P^{-1} A P$ as well (with an example eigenvector given by $w$).

This works for any $P$,
so if $A$ and $B$ are similar,
then every eigenvalue of $A$ is an eigenvalue of $B$,
and every eigenvalue of $B$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.
Therefore, $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks.
So we can conclude that if $v\neq 0$ is an eigenvector of $A$ (and $B$) so is $P^{-1}\cdot v$?

Comment: @gbox No--$A$ and $B$ do not have the same eigen*vectors*. They only have the same eigen*values*. If $B = P^{-1} A P$ and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ then $P^{-1}v$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.