# (True/false)if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable show that $g '(0)$ and $f' (0)$ have the same eigenvalues

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, examples-counterexamples

> Let $f,g:U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ differentiables in the open $U$ that contains $0$ and $f(0)=g(0)=0$. If $h\circ f=g\circ h$ and $h'(0):  \mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is an isomorphism. is it true that $f '(0)$ and $g' (0)$ have the same eigenvalues?

I've been trying to find a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}$ without success. Is there a counterexample?

Comment: Are you assuming that $h(0)=0$?

Comment: Not, the exercise does not assume that

Comment: Let $m = n = 1$. Let $f(x) = (x+1)^2-1$, $g(x) = x^2$ and $h(x) = x+1$. Then $f'(0) = 2$ and $g'(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By the Chain Rule,
$$h'(f(0)) \circ f'(0) = (h \circ f)'(0) = (g \circ h)'(0) = g'(h(0)) \circ h'(0),$$
which is the same as saying that $h'(0) \circ f'(0) \circ [h'(0)]^{-1} = g'(h(0))$. So, if $h(0) = 0$, then $f'(0)$ and $g'(0)$ has the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Could you explain to me why $h(0) = 0 $ implies that they have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: If $h(0) = 0$ and $T := h'(0)$, the equation $h'(0) \circ f'(0) \circ [h'(0)]^{-1} = g'(h(0))$ can be written as $T \circ f'(0) \circ T^{-1} = g'(0)$. So, if $h(0) = 0$, $f'(0)$ and $g'(0)$ are similar linear maps. Now, you can see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/similar-matrices-have-the-same-eigenvalues-with-the-same-geometric-multiplicity) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very helpful!. I see that the condition $h (0) = 0$ is necessary.